# Can I change CAGradientLayer() colors via an IBAction?

Tags: swift, cagradientlayer

I have the following extension file defined where I am setting a gradient for my UIView:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor) {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.blue, colorTwo.red]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
```

This links to a separate structs file, where I have defined four `UIColor`s:

```
blue,red,black,white
```

My viewcontroller.swift file has the following code within `viewDidLoad`:

```
myView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: Colors.blue, colorTwo: Colors.red)
```

This seems to work fine.

What I am trying to achieve is, when I click my `IBAction` button, it changes the `myView` colors to black and white (the remaining two colors). So I tried this:

```
@IBAction func hitButton(_ sender: Any) {

    myView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: Colors.black, colorTwo: Colors.white)

}
```

But this causes a crash: "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb25060a120"

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

The code you posted creates and adds a gradient layer to the view, and then forgets about it. If you call it more than once, you will wind up with more than one gradient layer. That's not what you want.

You really want to keep the gradient layer as a property of the view. To do that you should subclass the view rather than adding an extension (extensions can't add stored properties to classes.)

If you pass in colors to use for the gradient, it doesn't make sense to then use `colorOne.blue` `colorTwo.red` as the colors. Just use the colors that are passed to you.

Core Animation layers like `CAGradientLayer`s use CGColors, not UIColors. Taking those last 2 things together, this line:

```
gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.blue, colorTwo.red]
```

Should read

```
gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
```

instead.

You don't say which line is crashing, but passing the wrong data type to `gradientLayer.colors` is a likely culprit.